# Disabled hyperlink in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, hyperlink, textblock

I have a text block. When page is loaded -- I'm starting to fill it up with some elements:

```
textBlock.Inlines.Add("there will be ");

var link = new Hyperlink();
link.Inlines.Add("link!");
link.Click += Link_Click;
textBlock.Inlines.Add(link);

textBlock.Inlines.Add(". Like it?");
```

As you can see, among these elements is a hyperlink with a Click event handler. The problem is that the hyperlink sometimes becomes disabled. 
Ofcourse, Link_Click exists.

Enabled: Win7. Disabled: Win10.

How can it be? Any ideas?

*Edit 1.*

```
private async void Link_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
await EdSearchImpl(true, false);
}
```

Comment: Is this link exist under any control that is being disabled?

Comment: Yes, Aby. Each time I try to load it in Win10 -- the link is disabled. But in Win7 it works fine ...

Comment: Please include the source code for `Link_Click`.

Comment: Added handler to the question, @mjwills.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on `Link_Click` / `LinkRevert_Click` does it get hit when you click in Windows 7? In Windows 10?

Comment: @mjwills, on Win10 I can't even fire Click event, because it's disabled.

Comment: Where is your XAML? How and where is "textBlock" defined? Your issue is not anywhere near reproducible based on the (lack of) information you have provided.